# Send MongoDB db.serverStatus() output to a text file

Tags: mongodb-query

I am looking for the simplest way to direct from mongo shell the output of  db.serverStatus() to a text file.
If i try the pipe symbol  db.serverStatus() >> myoutput.txt I get Reference error: my output is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Javascript` to translate the result into a printable JSON.

```
mongo dbname command.js > output.txt
```

where `command.js` contains this (or its equivalent):

```
printjson( db.serverStatus())
```

By the way if you are running just a single Javascript statement you don't have to put it in a file and instead you can use:

```
mongo dbname --eval "printjson(db.serverStatus())" > output.txt
```

For reference: "http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/"

Explaination: The `eval` option will pass the mongo shell a JavaScript fragment which will return the output of db.serverStatus() using the mongo shell and then will output it to the 'output.txt' file.